# NSMutableArray storing integers

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I know this is probably basic...  I’m trying to store an answer to a multiple choice question (i.e. integer 1-4) stored in “selection”.  The question number is “gCount”.  This prints nil for the answerSubmit array.  What part is wrong? Thanks...

```
[answerSubmit insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:selection] atIndex:gCount];
NSLog(@"Answer submit: %@\n",[answerSubmit objectAtIndex:gCount]);
```

Comment: Did you initialize answerSubmit ? Post more code.

Comment: You need to explain and show a little more. How do you initialize the array?

Comment: Yes it was the initialization...

Comment: answerSubmit must be nil if "nil" is printed. NSArray will never return nil for `objectAtIndex:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have those two statements, exactly as shown, back-to-back in your program, and if the printed result was "Answer submit: (nil)", then "answerSubmit" is nil going in.